# Lagrange interpolation $f(x)-p_n(x)=f[x_0,x_1,...,x_n,x]\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)$

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

Let $f[x_0,x_1,...,x_k]$ be difference quotient with nodes $x_0,...,x_k$ (as in Newton's interpolation).

Let $p_n$ be Lagrange's interpolation polynomial of function $f$.

Prove for all $x$:
$$
f(x)-p_n(x)=f[x_0,x_1,...,x_n,x]\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)
$$
(I don't need to prove it when $x=x_i$)

I have tried to prove it using this theorem:
$$
f(x)-p(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)
$$
but my teacher said, that I don't need that, and that there is simpler proof. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you precise what is the definition you were given for $f[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an interpolation node... Let $p_n$ be the interpolating polynomial at $x_0, \cdots, x_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ the interpolating polynomial at $x_0, \cdots, x_n, x$, then we have

$$
p_{n+1}(t) = p_n(t) + f[x_0,\cdots, x_n, x](t-x_0)\cdots(t-x_n)
$$

Evaluating at $t=x$, you get simply

$$
\underbrace{p_{n+1}(x)}_{=f(x)} =  p_n(x) + f[x_0,\cdots, x_n, x](x-x0)\cdots(x-x_n)
$$

or

$$
f(x)-p_n(x)=f[x_0,\cdots, x_n, x](x-x0)\cdots(x-x_n).
$$

Note: The divided differences are precisely obtained in such a way that 
$$
p_{k+1}(x) = p_k(x) + c (x-x_0)\cdots (x-x_k),
$$ 
where $p_{k+1}$ is the interp.pol. at $x_0,\cdots x_k$, $p_{k}$ is the interp. pol. at $x_0,\cdots, x_{k-1}$ and the constant $c$ is defined as $f[x_0, \cdots, x_k]$.

Comment: ok, but why $p_{k+1}(x)=f(x)$?

Comment: @MartinYakuza Because $p_{n+1}$ is the interpolating polynomial at $x_0, \cdots, x_n,x$... So, $p_{n+1}(x_i)=f(x_i), i = 0, \cdots, n$ and $p_{n+1}(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: I get that $p_{n+1}(x_i)=f(x_i)$, but why would imply that $p_{n+1}(x)=f(x)$? E.g. let's assume $f(x)=x^3$ and we have nodes $x_0=0,\ x_1=1$, we get $p_2(x)=x$, adding node $x_2=2$ will transform it into $p_3(x)=x^2\neq f(x)$. I mean that the polynomial value equals function value in given nodes, and not for all $x$

Comment: @MartinYakuza I am defining $p_{n+1}$ as the interpolating polynomial at $x_0, \cdots, x_n$ AND $x$. So, $x$ is being handled as an additional interpolating point. So, by definition of $p_{n+1}$ we have that $p_{n+1}(x) = f(x)$. This is why I presented $p_{n+1}$ as a function of $t$.

Comment: ah ok, now I get it, thank you.